# JSON.stringify() behavior explanation

Tags: javascript

I am currently stuck on a thought about JSON.stringify() escaping.

```js
const g = {in: 'Game \\"'};
const str1 = JSON.stringify(g);

const gg = {in: 'Game \\\"'};
const str2 = JSON.stringify(gg);

console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
```

The output is equal. Why is that so?
Does JSON.stringify() handle escaping of "\" differently than other chars?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking (not least because it isn't clear if your code examples are actual data or are JavaScript string literals). Try using the live demo feature of the question editor to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I agree with @Quentin. I tried to guess what you mean adding formatting to your question. But it's still doubt

Comment: Btw, as a general rule, the backslash (`\ `)  **ALWAYS** escape the following character, even if that character isn't ambiguous. So in order to print a backslash character, you have to escape the backslash itself

Comment: Please provide more context. Why are you escaping JSON in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, just added more context and code that you guys can run. @Quentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JSON.stringify. It's entirely down to how the original string literals are parsed.

```js
const g = {in: 'Game \\"'};
const gg = {in: 'Game \\\"'};

console.log(g);
console.log(gg);
console.log(g.in === g.in);
```

## Your first example

```
\\"
```

1. A `\` which escapes the following character
2. A `\` which is escaped so means "A slash"
3. A `"` which has no special meaning in a string delimited by `'` so means "A double quote"

## Your second example

```
\\\"
```

1. A `\` which escapes the following character
2. A `\` which is escaped so means "A slash"
3. A `\` which escapes the following character
4. A `"` is escaped and *still* means "A double quote"

Comment: However both return \\\" after putting both into JSON.stringify(), why is that so?

Comment: @LeTuanAnh — Because both ```\``` and ```"``` have special meaning in JSON and need escaping.

Comment: Its a bit confusing for me still. When I input `JSON.stringify({in: '\"'})` it returns only `\"`. Should it return `\\\"` ?

Comment: @LeTuanAnh — No. That's like "Your second example" with the first two points in my list removed. You *only* have a double quote there.

Comment: @LeTuanAnh: Also keep in mind that there is a difference between *syntax* and the actual *value*. The actually value produced by the string literal `'\"'` `"`, i.e. a single quotation mark. The ``\`` is not part of the value. Escaped characters are only needed for the *parser* to parse the code correctly. When you JSON stringify the object/string you are stringifying the actual value, not its representation in the source code.